# Missing Dependencies/Headers in MSYS2 Ruby bundle (kgio and raindrops)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, mingw, msys2

Trying to narrow down the missing 'something', to no avail (maybe just fried my brain, anyone willing to help?)

kgio mkmf.log:
http://pastebin.com/1dRbhWq0

raindrops mkmf.log:
http://pastebin.com/bqbfPVTX

gem_make.out files in the comments (2 links limitation)

Comment: kgio gem_make.out:
http://pastebin.com/L40JpGU3
raindrops gem_make.out:
http://pastebin.com/y2s7Q7i0

Comment: You'll probably need to patch the kgio gem to get it to work under MinGW, which not a very Unix-like environment.  The current error might be fixable by teaching kgio's configure script to use the getaddrinfo function defined in mingw-w64's wspiapi.h header.  However, there might be dozens of other problems like this that would require careful thought.  The basic issue is that these gems are making low-level system calls that are not available in MinGW, and the gems were probably not designed to work on Windows.

Comment: Hmm, if it works in that DevKit then one way or another you should be able to figure out how it was built and then build it the same way in MSYS2's MINGW64 shell.  You might want to download the gem source code and try to build it yourself instead of using rubygems.

Comment: @DavidGrayson but if I download the source then why use the `bundle install` at all? I mean it defeats the purpose of it, and msys2's package manager. It would solve the problem but at best it's a work around. What I'm trying to look for is what library I'm missing, because I know the kgio is missing the `clock_gettime()` function and raindrops is missing `mmap()`. What I would like to know is what package does it belong to, for your reference, here is the list of packages from msys2: https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/ and https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages (duplicates?)

Comment: `clock_gettime` should already be on your system, and a prototype is provided in `/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/pthread_time.h` (which I found by using grep on that directory).  `mmap` is a complex system call and I don't think it is supported in MinGW.  You will have to investigate how to enable an alternate code path that doesn't use mmap, or write that code path yourself, or switch to a gem that supports Windows better.